# How can I use RegularExpressions to replace a match based on a pattern, but keep the value?

Tags: regex, swift, replace, pattern-matching, nsregularexpression

I want to replace all 'm's in my strings by 'meter'. The Problem is that I have to find the correct pattern, since it is possible to have a number in combination of a space in front of the unit symbol.

I already tried the following pattern: `[1-9][0-9]*\\s?m": "[1-9][0-9]*\\s?Meter` with the following code:

```
static let patterns = [
    "[1-9][0-9]*\\s?m": "[1-9][0-9]*\\s?Meter"
];

static public func prepareText(input: String) -> String {
    var modifiedInput = input;

    for pattern in patterns.keys {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive);
        modifiedInput = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(
            in: modifiedInput, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, modifiedInput.count),
            withTemplate: patterns[pattern]!);
    }

    return modifiedInput;
}
```

But now I have the problem that the value of my parameter is also changed:

```
800 m -> [1-9][0-9]*s?Meter
```

So how can I keep the 800 in front of the unit symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
static let patterns = [
    "([1-9][0-9]*\\s?)m": "$1Meter"
];
```

The `"([1-9][0-9]*\\s?)m"` pattern will match and capture into Group 1 a digit from `1` to `9`, any 0+ digits and then an optional whitespace, then just matches `m`. The `$1Meter` replacement will replace with the contents of Group 1 and then add `Meter`.

If you need to make sure the `m` is not followed with a word char, use `"([1-9][0-9]*\\s?)m\\b"` regex (that is, add `\\b`, a word boundary, after `m`).

Comment: Thank you for this really helpful answer!! This is the correct way to do!